# Finding a match in MySQL when comparing two comma delimited strings?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

OK, so I was thinking about using FIND_IN_SET but apparently it can only hand one item at a time? Basically I have something like this:

```
$valuesA = '48, 59, 206, 102, 8';
```

In the database, there is a table with rows and a column that might have some of these values. I will only be looking at one row, so I don't have to go through the whole table.

Example:

Row 215: valuesB column = '66, 84, 102, 559';

The item "102" should match.

I need a MySQL query that will return a match if ANY of the items in $valuesA matches anything in the valuesB column.

What would be the most efficient way to go about doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: If you're dealing with a set number of animals, using a bitmask would be pretty dang fast.

Answer (score 2):

Normalize the table. Values shouldn't be stored like that.

The most efficient (apart from normalizing) would be to simply `OR` all of them together.

Comment: Sorry, in the table they are actually ID's so instead of the word its just a number representation (5, 28, 485, 53) against the other numbers.

Comment: Even then, you still shouldn't store them like that.

Comment: Well I wouldn't have designed the table this way personally but currently there's no way to change the schema away from this. I'm pretty much stuck with OR for this?

Comment: You are, yes. MySQL assumes that (almost) all data is normalized.